# Building my own `like` system

Tags: database, api, reference, preferences

I am thinking to build my own `like` system, as a way of learning various technologies including Javascript; and to gain a better understanding of authentication and XSS.

#### Use-case:

1. Unique ID generated atop a little bit of Javascript code, for embedding in any website
2. When unique user presses this `like` button, a `+1` is triggered to the 'score' of that UID
3. On unique user's profile, display what they `like`'d

I'm unsure as where to start... **how would I go about building this system?**

Comment: what have you tried?  It's far better to ask specific questions than "how would I start...?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building such system is easy. Securing it properly, making it flow nice and be easy to integrate is the hardest part. You should ignore the latter 3 for now. I would start with a JS file that searches the DOM for any elements with the ID of "mylike" (for example) which inserts a button on to said page. Once a user clicks the button it simply does an AJAX post back to your server containing information like the page title and page URL. I think it may be best for your backend to generate the ID, maybe an algorithm based on the title + URL.

To include user data to know what user liked what I'd suggest a persistent cookie that has a session variable to link to a user in your back end. Simply pull the cookie out using JavaScript and send the cookie along with the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for the information, very helpful! - Also, would I be using a web-framework for this, in order to CRUD with the database and javascript?

Comment: Yes, you would need some sort of back-end to talk with your database. I'd recommend C# ASP.NET and the MVC 3.0 framework.

Comment: Is C# with ASP.NET better than DJango? - Which will lower the devel time, and which will have better speeds?

Comment: I've never used Django so I can't comment but I do hear good things about it. It all comes down to personal preference and what your familiar in. I think it will be easier to find a ASP.NET developer.